# Why does my component fail to construct Url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm fairly new to React development and hope someone can help me with this problem. I'm coding along with a YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtMThy8QKqU&t=10138s (2:55:00 shows what it is supposed to do)and for some reason I can't find the mistake I'm making. When I test my app on localhost the window in which the trailer is supposed to play is only displayed when I click certain movie covers but not when I click on others. my other problem is that it will never actually play a trailer. The console displays the error you can hopefully see here [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC6Sh.jpg

```
import movieTrailer from "movie-trailer";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import YouTube from "react-youtube";
import axios from "./axios";
import "./Row.css"


const base_url = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/";

function Row({ title, fetchUrl, isLargeRow }) {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
    const [trailerUrl, setTrailerUrl] = useState("");

    //A snippet of code which runs based on a specific condition or variable
    useEffect(() => {
    // if brackets are blank [] it means run once when row loads, and don't run again
         async function fetchData() {
             const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);
                // console.log(request.data.results);
             setMovies(request.data.results)
             return request;
        // async function fetchData() {
        //     try{
        //         const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);
        //         console.log(request);
        //         return request;
        //     }
        //     catch (error){
        //         console.log(error);
        //     }

        }
        fetchData();
        }, [fetchUrl]);

        const opts = {
            height: '390',
            width: '100%',
            playerVars: {
              // https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters
              autoplay: 1,
            },
        };
        
        //console.log(movies);

        const handleClick = (movie) => {
            if (trailerUrl){
                setTrailerUrl('');
            } else {
                movieTrailer(movie?.name || "")
                .then ((url) => {
                    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(new URL(url).search);
                    setTrailerUrl(urlParams.get("v"));
                }).catch(error => console.log(error));
            }
        };

    return(
        <div className="row">
            <h2>{title}</h2>

            <div className="row__posters">
                {movies.map(movie => (
                    <img 
                        key={movie.id}
                        onClick={() => handleClick(movie)}
                        className= {`row__poster ${isLargeRow && "row__posterLarge"}`}
                        src={`${base_url}${isLargeRow ? movie.poster_path : movie.backdrop_path}`} alt={movie.name}/>
                ))}
             </div> 
             {trailerUrl && <YouTube videoId="{trailerUrl}" opts={opts} /> }

        </div>
    )
}

export default Row
```

Answer (score 0):

**Invalid property `name` in `movie`**

Taking a look at the [tmdb docs](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-top-rated-movies) it will show you what the properties of each object has. In this case, there is no `name`. Try using something like `movie.title`

In your `handleClick()` function you could use `movie?.title`.

Trying to use `movie.name` will give back a null value. Which errors out movieTrailer() and you get no YouTube url back.

Answer (score 0):

Create handle function like this and the call it in your return function and use however you want... mainly should be used by using onClick method
[image]

Comment: Please: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).